# Why is no audio playing when I press any button in my app?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a small app in android studio with 8 buttons that play a soundbite for each button. My code appears to be correct but when I actually run the app on my android device and press any of the buttons no sound is produced.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SoundPool soundPool;
private int work_it1, make_it2, do_it3, make_us4, harder5, better6, faster7, stronger8;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();

        soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(8)
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                .build();
    } else {
        soundPool = new SoundPool(8, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }

    work_it1 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.work_it1, 1);
    make_it2 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.make_it2, 1);
    do_it3 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.do_it3, 1);
    make_us4 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.make_us4, 1);
    harder5 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.harder5, 1);
    better6 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.better6, 1);
    faster7 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.faster7, 1);
    stronger8 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.stronger8, 1);
}
public void playSound(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
        soundPool.play(work_it1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            soundPool.play(make_it2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            soundPool.play(do_it3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            soundPool.play(make_us4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.button5:
            soundPool.play(harder5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.button6:
            soundPool.play(better6, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.button7:
            soundPool.play(faster7, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.button8:
            soundPool.play(stronger8, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            break;
    }
}
```

I've tried messing with the priorities but that doesn't seem to fix anything. I'm not sure what else to do, I'd appreciate any help.
To be clear inside of a separate file that defines the actual layout of the app there are 8 buttons that call playSound() they all look similar to this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="176dp"
    android:layout_height="113dp"
    android:text="faster"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.068"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.83"
    android:onClick="playSound"/>
```

Comment: I do see you created that method `playSound()` ... but what makes you think this method will be called? Defining a method alone doesnt mean it gets invoked?! I guess it works the other way round: you have to tell each button that WHEN clicked, the button needs to trigger some action.

Comment: Sorry for not being 100% clear, I have been invoking playSound from a different file the other script has 8 buttons all reading basically like this :
<Button
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.83"
        android:onClick="playSound"/>
So the buttons do invoke playSound and since all 8 have different IDs the playSound (should) play the different audios according to the ID but no audio is produced

Comment: Please do not provide such information in comments. Always update your question instead! And please read [mcve] to ensure you consider all relevant aspects needed. Seriously: dont leave out pieces of code because you **think** they arent relevant. Try to reduce your problem to the smallest set that shows the problem, and then provide that as a whole to us.